# table - delete the line under table

Tags: tables

How to delete this line please? Thank you.
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\setlength\textwidth{145mm}
\setlength\textheight{247mm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\evensidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\topmargin{0mm}
\setlength\headsep{0mm}
\setlength\headheight{0mm}
\let\openright=\clearpage
\usepackage[a-2u]{pdfx}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, graphicx,threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\NewDocumentCommand{\anote}{}{\makebox[0pt][l]{$^*$}}



\usepackage{amsfonts}       % matematické fonty
\usepackage{amsthm}         % sazba vět, definic apod.
\usepackage{bbding}         % balíček s nejrůznějšími symboly
                % (čtverečky, hvězdičky, tužtičky, nůžtičky, ...)
\usepackage{bm}             % tučné symboly (příkaz \bm)
\usepackage{fancyvrb}       % vylepšené prostředí pro strojové písmo
\usepackage{indentfirst}    % zavede odsazení 1. odstavce kapitoly
\usepackage{natbib}         % zajištuje možnost odkazovat na literaturu
                % stylem AUTOR (ROK), resp. AUTOR [ČÍSLO]
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % zajistí přidání seznamu literatury,
\usepackage{icomma}         
\usepackage{booktabs}       % lepší vodorovné linky v tabulkách
\usepackage{paralist}       % lepší enumerate a itemize
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.25ex}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{,}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\stack[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack{#1}}}
\newcommand{\angstrom}{\mbox{\normalfont\AA}}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{%
   \bgroup%
   \setlength\extrarowheight{0pt}%
   \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}%
   \egroup}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchparametertext\@cline{-}{\cA-}{}{}
\makeatother
\hfuzz=99pt

\begin{document}



    \begin{table}[ht!]
    \scriptsize
    \renewcommand{\cellset}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.75}\scriptsize}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C|*{2}{C} >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}C >{\hsize=1.3\hsize}Cc*{3}{C}}
    \Xhline{1.2pt}\noalign{\vskip 0.4ex}\Xhline{1.2pt}%
    \multirowcell{4}{Veličina} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{[1]} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{[2]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{[3]} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{[4]} \\[0.4ex]
    \cline{2-9}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirowcell{1.5}{PHOEBE fotometrie a RV}}
     &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{POWR\\ analýza}} & %
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{Řešení\\ světelných\\ křivek a RV}} &
   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \multirowcell{3}{CFF }}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \multirowcell{3}{Model\\malá\\ hmotnost}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{Model\\ střední\\ hmotnost}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{3}{Model\\ velká\\ hmotnost}} \\[1ex]
    \cline{2-3}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{1.5}{Řešení II}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowcell{1.5}{Řešení III}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\ [1.5ex]

    \Xhline{1.2pt}%

\makecell{$R_2$\\  ($\mathrm{R}_{\odot}$)}& 7&  4,8&    6,5&    5&  &   5&  4,92&   5,17\\
&&&&&&\\[-10pt]
\hline
&&&&&&\\[-10pt]
\makecell{$V_{\gamma}$\\ (\si{\kilo\meter\per\second})}&    21,77(51)&  21,74(50)&  &   15,5(7)&    &   15,51&  15,71&  15,34\\
&&&&&&\\[-10pt]

     \Xhline{1.2pt}%
     \smallskip

     \end{tabularx}
\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\footnotesize
 \begin{scriptsize}
  \textit{Pozn:}
  Čísla v~závorkách jsou chyby posledních uvedených cifer.
  $^*$~značí fixované parametry.
  \end{scriptsize}
}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

And in original file I have black rectangle. How to hide it? I have a \hfuzz=99pt in preamble.
[image]

Comment: Put the parbox below `\end{tabularx}`.

Comment: Why are you using `threeparttable` herre?

Comment: Thank you a black rectangle is out. threeparttable  shouldn't be there. I Change the code in my question. And the line below the table?

Comment: What tool did you use to generate this table?

Comment: I use MIKTeX to compilation

Comment: That is not what i meant. Which table generator do you use that generates that gibberish code? The table as is is (imho) not well designed (output), but the input is just crazy.

Comment: Delete the final occurrence of  `&&&&&&\\[-10pt]` and move the instruction `\smallskip` so that it occurs after, not before, `\end{tabularx}`.

Comment: @Johannes_B - To answer your question in all painful detail, just follow the OP's series of postings to TeX.SE in recent weeks...

Comment: Thank you Mico, it works. I am sorry Johannes_B I don't know the answer, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @Mico "Well, that escalated quickly" :-) Elisabeth: `booktabs`% lepší vodorovné linky v tabulkách -> Why don't you have a look at its documentation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get rid of the protruding vertical line, you need to (a) get rid of the final instance of `&&&&&&\\[-10pt]` and (b) move the `\smallskip` instruction so that it occurs after, not before, `\end{tabularx}`.

I can't help but comment that the code chunk

```
\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\footnotesize
 \begin{scriptsize}
  \textit{Pozn:}
  Čísla v~závorkách jsou chyby posledních uvedených cifer.
  $^*$~značí fixované parametry.
  \end{scriptsize}
}
```

seems extraordinarily convoluted. It can be (and should be!) replaced with

```
\textit{Pozn:} Čísla v~závorkách jsou chyby posledních uvedených cifer. 
$^*$~značí fixované parametry.
```